# Bulk change radio button setting in admin/content using database

Tags: 7, nodes, database

I am using a paywall module called TinyPass where I have to check a radio button in order to activate the paywall for a specific node. I now have a situation where I want to uncheck (or deactivate) this button for a lot of nodes that I have.

Instead of doing this for every individual node I would like to do this for a large selection of nodes (or even all of them).

Is it possible at all to change the value of these radio buttons setting in a node using the database or some other solution? This would save me a ton of time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried bulk operations? You can select a bunch of nodes from the content overview page, and use bulk operations to change values on all of them. https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations